# Write from a resultset to ORC file

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to write to an orc file from a resultset. Getting an error 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.type.HiveVarchar
I am trying to write without a map reduce job.

```
    final static OrcSerde serde = new OrcSerde();
    final Writer writer = OrcFile.createWriter(hdfs, OrcPath, conf, oi, stripeSize, CompressionKind.SNAPPY, compressBufferSize, rowIndexStride);

            final List<Object> record = new LinkedList<>();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; ++column) {
                    switch (columnTypes[column]) {
                    case Types.BOOLEAN:
                        record.add(resultSet.getBoolean(column));
                        break;
                    case Types.CHAR:
                    case Types.VARCHAR:
                        record.add(resultSet.getString(column));
                        break;
                    case Types.SMALLINT:
                    case Types.INTEGER:
                        record.add(resultSet.getInt(column));
                        break;
                    case Types.BIGINT:
                        record.add(resultSet.getString(column));
                        break;
                    case Types.FLOAT:
                    case Types.DECIMAL:
                    case Types.DOUBLE:
                        record.add(resultSet.getDouble(column));
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new RuntimeException
                    }
                    if (resultSet.wasNull()) {
                        record.remove(record.size());
                        record.add(null);
                    }
                }

                writer.addRow(record);
              }
            writer.close();
        }
}
```